# Angular 4 pre-rendering with a components library using .net core 2.0

Tags: angular-universal, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I understand that any components library that depends on window or document cannot be used while we pre-render an angular app.

Does this mean it is practically not possible to pre-render an app without writing our own components library and making it somehow not dependent on window? if there was an amicable way of doing it, people would have already done it, right ?

this begs the question what strategies people have followed while successfully pre-rendering an angular app and also using an external components library ? if there is no way of doing that, are people using pre-rendering without any such library in prod ?

I have gone through all the possible solutions to make angular material work with aspnetcore 2.0 pre-rendering and none of them has worked, eg: angular-ssr

Any kind of strategy advice is hugely appreciated, this makes me also wonder if pre-rendering is such a pain in angular and very important for the business side of an app, using react is a better strategy ?